# PHP code to generate small size bill receipt

Tags: php

i need help in order to generate a simple small size bill receipt as displayed in the link 
http://christinesreviews.com/reviews/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bill-Mogambo-978x1024.jpg
I have searched it on google and i am finding the large size invoice code instead of what is required by me. Please guide me as how could i generate the exact replica of the above displayed image.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: so you want a dynamic receipt? that looks exactly like the picture. Have you tried anything so far? Because we are not here, to do your work

Comment: Yes @lino, i want a dynamic receipt. The codes i tried were all related to generating large size invoices, not the small ones. Regarding that, i haven't found anything. Thanks ..

Comment: Are you getting the data out of a database?

Comment: yes, i am using cakephp framework to develop the project and i am able to extract the required data out of database.

Comment: can you edit your answer, so we can see what exactly has to be dynamic on that form?

Comment: The list of products as purchased by the customer with the customer details will be from database. the company details will be static.

Comment: ok, give me some time and i will give you an answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ......... :) I will also update you if i find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML to print such a small invoice using the @print rule in css..
all you have to do it to print the bill to a normal html page and style the page to print using @print.. I hope this work

Comment: Thanks Adarsh ..!! I will try this and will get back to you soon. But i want a dynamic receipt. So with the @print rule, is it possible to print a dynamic receipt.??

Comment: make the div element that contains the main bill not to.increase its width dynamically

Comment: remember to use either cm,mm or inch as the unit for printing

Comment: the actual width of the paper to which you are planning to print

Comment: ok..... thanks a lot sir...... it will take some time to try and implement this. I will surely get back to you with the output. Any other suggestions sir.

Comment: try it and let me know..:D